# Access Denied when compiling c code with gcc

Tags: gcc, c

I compiled my c program with `gcc -c -o test.exe test.c`
and it compiled with no errors and then when I run it gives `Access is denied.`

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it without the `-c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try it without the `-c`
>   By @Scott

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple kinds of binary / object / executable code files. 
I’m not sure how standard these names are,
but [CS 11: Compiling C programs](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html) (at Caltech)
refers to “object files” and “binary executables”. 
A simple (perhaps over-simplified) explanation is that an object file
contains the instructions produced by compiling a single source file,
while a binary executable represents a complete program. 
(Once you get beyond the “Hello world” level of programming,
it is common to have multiple source code files to build a single program.) 
Object files are, more-or-less by definition, *incomplete* programs,
and therefore are not executable.

When you compile with `-c`, you are creating an object file,
which contains your `main` function, and nothing else. 
It contains the *call* to `printf`,
but it doesn’t contain the `printf` function itself,
or the means of finding / loading it. 
You must leave off the  `-c`option,
so you get a binary executable of the complete program.